# Asyncio task vs coroutine

Tags: python-asyncio

Reading the [asyncio documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines), I realize that I don't understand a very basic and fundamental aspect: the difference between awaiting a coroutine directly, and awaiting the same coroutine when it's wrapped inside a task.

In the documentation examples the two calls to the `say_after` coroutine are running sequentially when awaited without `create_task`, and concurrently when wrapped in `create_task`. So I understand that this is basically the difference, and that it is quite an important one.

However what confuses me is that in the example code I read everywhere (for instance showing how to use `aiohttp`), there are many places where a (user-defined) coroutine is awaited (usually in the middle of some other user-defined coroutine) without being wrapped in a task, and I'm wondering why that is the case. What are the criteria to determine when a coroutine should be wrapped in a task or not?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> What are the criteria to determine when a coroutine should be wrapped in a task or not?

You should use a **task** when you want your coroutine to effectively run **in the background**. The code you've seen just awaits the coroutines directly because it needs them running in sequence. For example, consider an HTTP client sending a request and waiting for a response:

```py
# these two don't make too much sense in parallel
await session.send_request(req)
resp = await session.read_response()
```

There are situations when you *want* operations to run in parallel. In that case `asyncio.create_task` is the appropriate tool, because it turns over the responsibility to execute the coroutine to the event loop. This allows you to start several coroutines and sit idly while they execute, typically waiting for some or all of them to finish:

```py
dl1 = asyncio.create_task(session.get(url1))
dl2 = asyncio.create_task(session.get(url2))
# run them in parallel and wait for both to finish
resp1 = await dl1
resp2 = await dl2

# or, shorter:
resp1, resp2 = asyncio.gather(session.get(url1), session.get(url2))
```

As shown above, a task can be awaited as well. Just like awaiting a coroutine, that will block the current coroutine until the coroutine driven by the task has completed. In analogy to threads, awaiting a task is roughly equivalent to join()-ing a thread (except you get back the return value). Another example:

```py
queue = asyncio.Queue()

# read output from process in an infinite loop and
# put it in a queue
async def process_output(cmd, queue, identifier):
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(cmd)
    while True:
        line = await proc.readline()
        await queue.put((identifier, line))

# create multiple workers that run in parallel and pour
# data from multiple sources into the same queue
asyncio.create_task(process_output("top -b", queue, "top")
asyncio.create_task(process_output("vmstat 1", queue, "vmstat")

while True:
    identifier, output = await queue.get()
    if identifier == 'top':
        # ...
```

In summary, if you need the result of a coroutine in order to proceed, you should just await it without creating a task, i.e.:

```py
# this is ok
resp = await session.read_response()
# unnecessary - it has the same effect, but it's
# less efficient
resp = await asyncio.create_task(session.read_reponse())
```

To continue with the threading analogy, creating a task just to await it immediately is like running `t = Thread(target=foo); t.start(); t.join()` instead of just `foo()` - inefficient and redundant.

Comment: Awesome answer. Do you mind sharing few more conceptual answers by you in the comments?

Comment: When you say tasks are executed in background ,  can you elaborate on it?

Comment: Yeah, aren't tasks are just switched back and forth anyway? How that "running in background" is different?

Comment: @Andrius Not sure what you're asking - the answer does say (in boldface) that the started coroutine effectively runs in the background. Compared to threads, the difference is that with threads the switch can happen anywhere, and on a multicore system it's possible (when using code implemented with extensions that release the GIL) to get true parallel execution. Asyncio is strictly single-threaded, so any mention of background must come with a disclaimer.

Comment: Ok. I was confused a bit about background thing, thinking maybe it was implied that it does some concurrency, which of course clearly is not

Comment: @Andrius Well, asyncio tasks _do_ run _concurrently_, but not _in parallel_.

Comment: @pepoluan right. Yeah I meant parallelism