# What is the most convenient way to map a Coroutine for asynchronous execution in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, python-asyncio, python-decorators

I am trying to "map" an `Iterable` asynchronously over multiple functions in a Python project. I have found a few ways to do this, namely:

- **Method 1**: `asyncio.gather` (this works).
- **Method 2**: A regular `for` loop (this  does not work, shown for reference).
- **Method 3**: A decorator that accepts an `Iterable` as input along with the name of an argument for injection (this works too and is equivalent to **Method 1**).

Below is the code:

```py
from asyncio import AbstractEventLoop
from datetime import datetime
from functools import wraps
from typing import AsyncIterable, Coroutine, Iterable, List, Union
import asyncio
import inspect
import os


ITERATIONS: List[int] = list(range(3))


def map_async(
        iterable: Union[AsyncIterable, Iterable],
        kwarg: str,
    ) -> Coroutine:
    """
    A decorator that maps an iterable for asynchronous
    consumption by a Coroutine.

    Parameters
    ----------
    iterable : Union[AsyncIterable, Iterable]
        An iterable (either sync or async).
    kwarg : str
        Name of the argument to inject into the wrapped Coroutine
        for each iteration of the iterable.
    """
    def wrapper(async_func: Coroutine):
        @wraps(async_func)
        async def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            if inspect.isasyncgen(iterable):
                return await asyncio.gather(
                    *[
                        async_func(*args, **{kwarg: xx}, **kwargs)
                        async for xx in iterable
                    ]
                )
            else:
                return await asyncio.gather(
                    *(
                        async_func(*args, **{kwarg: xx}, **kwargs)
                        for xx in iterable
                    )
                )
        return wrapped
    return wrapper


# Method 1 (a):
async def foo(count: int, sleep_duration: int):
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_duration)
    print(count)


# Method 1 (b):
async def async_foo_gather(sleep_duration: int):
    await asyncio.gather(*(foo(count, sleep_duration) for count in ITERATIONS))


# Method 2:
async def async_foo_for(sleep_duration: int):
    for count in ITERATIONS:
        await foo(count, sleep_duration)


# Method 3:
@map_async(iterable=ITERATIONS, kwarg='count')
async def async_foo_mapped(sleep_duration: int, **kwargs):
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_duration)
    print(kwargs['count'])


if __name__ == '__main__':

    loop: AbstractEventLoop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    TERMINAL_SIZE = os.get_terminal_size()

    hrule: str = '-' * TERMINAL_SIZE.columns

    print(hrule)

    # Method 1: asyncio.gather over an Iterable.

    print('async_foo_gather')
    start: datetime = datetime.now()
    loop.run_until_complete(async_foo_gather(sleep_duration=5))
    stop: datetime = datetime.now()
    print('DURATION: ', (stop - start).total_seconds())

    print(hrule)

    # Method 2: synchronous for loop.

    print('async_foo_for')
    start: datetime = datetime.now()
    loop.run_until_complete(async_foo_for(sleep_duration=5))
    stop: datetime = datetime.now()
    print('DURATION: ', (stop - start).total_seconds())

    print(hrule)

    # Method 3: map_async decorator.

    print('async_foo_mapped')
    start: datetime = datetime.now()
    loop.run_until_complete(async_foo_mapped(sleep_duration=5))
    stop: datetime = datetime.now()
    print('DURATION: ', (stop - start).total_seconds())

    print(hrule)
```

This results in the following output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
async_foo_gather
0
1
2
DURATION:  5.000184
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
async_foo_for
0
1
2
DURATION:  15.00077
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
async_foo_mapped
0
1
2
DURATION:  5.001652
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Method 1** and **Method 3** are equivalent but I feel like there must be a more elegant or idiomatic way to do this?

Helpers such as the `map_async` decorator etc could live in their own module but, overall, I'd really appreciate something that saves having to define two functions in *each* usage (as in **Method 1**, nested or otherwise) because this transformation is needed in many places.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question? The use of `gather` is quite idiomatic in asyncio. Your `for` loop doesn't work because `await` actually waits for each iteration to finish before proceeding to the next one. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57968602/1600898) for details.

Comment: Method 1 is the most elegant & idiomatic in my opinion. If a unit of work can be mapped it can be named also, thus having two functions just makes your code more readable.