# When to convert a coroutine to a task?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I read the following code for a Tornado web service. It calls a function `do_work()` periodically.

```
event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def run_periodically(interval, func):
    while True:
        print(f"...{datetime.datetime.now()}")
        await func()
        await asyncio.sleep(interval)

print(f"start.... {datetime.datetime.now()}")
func = lambda: do_work("arg_1", kw1="kw_1")
task = event_loop.create_task(run_periodically(10, func))  # is create_task() needed here?
# task = run_periodically(10, func)  # this line works too
event_loop.run_until_complete(task)

tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Does it make any sense to create a task for `run_periodically()`? Replace the line with `task = run_periodically(10, func)` works fine.

---

do_work() example,

```
async def do_work(arg1, kw1):
    """To be run periodically"""
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(f"...{datetime.datetime.now()}: args: {arg1} kwargs: {kw1}")
```

Comment: You see no difference, because the `run_until_complete()` converts a coroutine argument into a task.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use the task and co-routine interchangeable as it is running in the foreground. You would need to have the co-routine wrapped in a task when you want to run it in the background. You can read about it more here on this well written answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57968602